# Close dialog and navigate to a new route with an dialog open having problems in Angular 4

Tags: angular

I have searched couple of hours, but not found any similar post.

Problem description:

I click a button in routeA component, it will navigate to routeB and open a dialogB, and after I close this dialogB, it will navigate back to routeA. In the constructor of the routeA component, I have a dialogA is open when this compoennt is initialised(inside constructor()). And the error occured in the console, saying that there is a error in routeA component, which pointing to the EventEmitter of dialogA in the constructor.

> Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined

I could get around this issue using

```
path = window.location.pathname;
```

Then just check if the path equal to the route of destination component,

```
if (path != '/merchant/(page:home)' && path != '/merchant'){
```

but the case is I do have couple of components having the same logic to open a dialog from their constructor, which makes this approve less maintainable. And it only occured for those component which contain the code to open a dialog in the constructor.

I am wondering is there anything I could do to solve my problem, or should I re-design my structrue?

*Example code to illustrate the problem*

routeA component with dialogA:

```
constructor() {
let ref = this.dialog.open(DashboardIntroModalComponent, {
  width: "800px",
  panelClass: "noCard"
});

if (ref.componentInstance.showOnDashLogin == true) {
  ref.close();
}
else {
  const sub = ref.componentInstance.closeModal.subscribe(data => {
    ref.close();
  });
  // const tour = ref.componentInstance.startTour.subscribe(data => {

  //   ref.close();
  //   this.startTour();
  // });

}
}
```

open dialogB:

```
let ref = AppComponent.dialog.open(LookupComponent, {
  data: {
    autoFocus: true,
    isModal: true
  },
  width: "650px",
});

ref.componentInstance.getResult.subscribe(res => {
  if (res) {
    ref.close();

    this.router.navigate([
      "/merchant",
      {
        outlets: {
          page: ['customer-profile', res['ID']]
        }
      }
    ])
  }
})

let path = window.location.pathname;


ref.componentInstance.close.subscribe(res => {
  if (res == true) {
    ref.close();
    this.location.back()
  }
})
```

Comment: can you create stackblitz example of your problem for better understanding of your problem

Comment: sure, I will add the link once I have the example ready

Comment: Explain expected behaviour also. In dialog A, there is a navigate mentioned is that the previous navigation?

Comment: @raghulselvam I edited my description, see if it explain better?

Comment: just move your initializations from constructor to ngOnInit() method

Comment: After navigate back to routeA from routeB, the dialogA should open but it showing error. This is the problem right. Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @raghulselvam totally correct, thank for that, I should just mention that in my description

Answer (score 0):

I believe this issue is because "res"  variable executed before its initialized. Try to add the code inside constructor to `ngAfterViewInit()` method.

RouteA
// Implement AfterViewInit in the class

```
Constructor () { }

ngAfterViewInit () { 
let ref = this.dialog.open(DashboardIntroModalComponent, {
  width: "800px",
  panelClass: "noCard"
});

if (ref.componentInstance.showOnDashLogin == true) {
  ref.close();
}
else {
  const sub = ref.componentInstance.closeModal.subscribe(data => {
    ref.close();
  });
}

}
```

Comment: Thank you, but the problem remains after I put the code into ngAfterViewInit()

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding a extra field in the data attribute when setting up the routes.

something like this

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'componet path',
    component: ComponentPath,
    data: { openDialog: 'componet path' },
    outlet: 'page'
  },
]
```

In my routeA component

```
ngInit() {
  this.router.events
  .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
  .map(() => this.activatedRoute)
  .map(route => {
    while (route.firstChild) route = route.firstChild;
    return route;
  })
  .mergeMap(route => route.data)
  .subscribe(event => {
    if (event['openDialog']) {
      this.routerPath = event['openDialog'];
      this.hasDialogInConstrcutor = true;
    }
  });
}
```

button to open dialogA

```
ref.componentInstance.close.subscribe(res => {
  if (res == true) {
    ref.close();
    if (this.hasDialogInConstrcutor == true) {
      this.router.navigate([
        '/merchant', {
          outlets: {page: [this.routerPath]}
        }
      ]);
    }
    else {
      this.location.back();
    }
  }
})
```